# Improving setValueForKeyPath robustness

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, key-value-coding, defensive-programming

I have created an extension to NSObject to allow for object properties to be set from data contained in a PLIST or dictionary.  I did use `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary` but this only works for keys not keyPaths.  My extension does the same thing, except allows the PLIST to contain key paths as well as keys.  For example, detailTextLabel.text @"detailed text" as the key value pair.

This works well, except it is possible to crash the app because of a typo in the PLIST.  For instance, it will crash if the property name exists but is a different type that expected (a number instead of a string for instance).  What is the best way to make this more robust and code defensively to avoid these types of errors?

I am already using `- (void) setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {}` in my objects to trap items in the PLIST that don't correspond to actual keys.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Extensions to NSObject

@implementation NSObject (SCLibrary)

- (void) setValuesForKeyPathsWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *) keyPathValues {
    NSArray *keys;
    int i, count;
    id key, value;

    keys = [keyPathValues allKeys];
    count = [keys count];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        key = [keys objectAtIndex: i];
        value = [keyPathValues objectForKey: key];

        [self setValue:value forKeyPath:key];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, Dave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have added a general `@try/@catch` around the `setValue:forKeyPath:`

```
@try {
    [self setValue:value forKeyPath:key];
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"%@",e);
}
```

Which does prevent the app from crashing, however I was hoping to find an approach that checked for the selector before trying to set its value.

Will accept this answer if a better one is not forthcoming.